# How can I split a string on parenthesis in java except those which are present inside words

Tags: java

My string for example is :

(My Na(#me is Sameer)

I want the output while splitting on parenthesis as :

(

My

Na(#me

is

Sameer

)

Comment: Strip the parenthesis off the ends then split on space. No?

Answer (score 1):

I would start up by **splitting it using any space character** as a separator (i.e. `" \t\r\n"`).

```
    String challenge = "(My Na(me is Sameer)";
    String[] parts = challenge.split("\\s*");
```

But also multiple consecutive spaces are handled as 1 separator. You don't want to have an empty String (i.e. `""`) whenever there are 2 consecutive spaces.

Next, I will put everything in a `List`. First of all, because it is my impression that in reality you don't just want to print this text. You probably want to use them somewhere else in your code, e.g. by passing them as an argument to another method.

There are multiple list types to pick from (e.g. `ArrayList`). In this case, I need to do one more modification to the content of the list. I'm planning to **split elements if they start or end with a bracket** `(` or `)`. For this reason I'm using a `LinkedList`. Because linked lists are more performant to insert elements halfway the list.

```
    List<String> partList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(parts));
```

So here we go, let's iterate all elements. If an element starts with a bracket, then split it up in 2 elements. For elements that end with a bracket same thing.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < partList.size(); i++) {
        String part = partList.get(i);
        if (part.startsWith("(")) {
            partList.set(i, part.substring(1));
            partList.add(i, "(");
        } else if (part.endsWith(")")) {
            partList.set(i, part.substring(0, part.length() - 1));
            partList.add(i + 1, ")");
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Now, notice that I'm incrementing the index when I add a `")"` element, which is necessary to avoid an endless loop.

And there is **some shortcoming in this approach**. If you would have a phrase that looks like this: `"(((mytext)))"` It may not do what you hoped for. But I'm assuming that this is outside the scope of your question. It could be solved by adding more code, but I didn't want to make it too complicated.

Finally I'm printing everything.

```
    for (String part : partList) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
```

## EDIT:

For the sake of being complete. The following implementation is slightly more complicated, but also tackles the corner cases.

```
    String challenge = "((this is a) rea(lly go)od (((challenge))))";
    String[] parts = challenge.split("\\s");
    List<String> partList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(parts));

    for (int i = 0; i < partList.size(); i++) {
        String part = partList.get(i);

        // avoid eternal loops
        if (part.length() == 1) continue;

        if (part.startsWith("(")) {
            partList.set(i, part.substring(1));
            partList.add(i, "(");

            // will reprocess, because the part is automatically shifted 1 position in the list.
        }
        else if (part.endsWith(")")) {
            partList.set(i, part.substring(0, part.length() - 1));
            partList.add(i+1, ")");

            // reprocess this element, there could be more ")" braces.
            i--;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking some help you should come up with what you have tried so far. In here you can do following things.

1. split your original String by space.
2. then you can iterate the resulting substrings and check whether a substring contains parenthesis either start or the end of the substring. If so you can split them again by parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

If parenthesis appears only at the beginning and end of the sentence then split it first with substring and then with spaces.

If the parenthesis can appear anywhere in the middle of the sentence(start or end  of the word), then first spilt the based on white space, then iterate through each word and spilt again based on parenthesis at start and end of the word. You can use below code (of course, this can be enhanced further)

```
String test = "(My Na(me (is) Jack)";
String[] splitWords = test.split(" ");
for (String word : splitWords) {
    int size = word.length();
    if (word.startsWith("(") && word.endsWith(")")) {
        System.out.println("(");
        System.out.println(word.substring(1, size - 1));
        System.out.println(")");
    } else if (word.startsWith("(") && !word.endsWith(")")) {
        System.out.println("(");
        System.out.println(word.substring(1, size ));
    } else if (!word.startsWith("(") && word.endsWith(")")) {
        System.out.println(word.substring(0, size - 1));
        System.out.println(")");
    } else {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

This will produce the output as below.

```
(
My
Na(me
(
is
)
Jack
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match only the parenthesis you want: `\B[)(]\b|\b[)(]\B|\B[)(]\B`

Here it is as a Java String:

```
"\\B[)(]\\b|\\b[)(]\\B|\\B[)(]\\B"
```

`\b` matches word boundaries

`\B` matches non-word boundaries

Comment: Part of your suggestion worked in my case.
Thanks :-)

Comment: This regex is not working if there certain special characters in the string.
for example my string is :
(My Na(#me is Sameer).
It is not giving proper spliting output.

Comment: @Sameer That's because `#` isn't considered to be part of a "word". Feel free to edit your question into shape to better reflect what you're asking for.

Comment: Then what will be the regex, if I had to consider special charcter also along with it.

Comment: @Sameer What do you consider a word? is it a string of characters surrounded by whitespace?

Comment: I am considering word as a string characters surrounded by white spaces. These characters include special character also. I had edited my question. You can check there what I want.